# Conditional Attributes in Blazor

Tags: c#, blazor, blazor-server-side

I have a recursive `Blazor` component that has an optional parameter.

If the parameter is null, it shouldn’t attempt to pas the parameter as that causes an error.

How can I avoid this?

```
> @if(param == null){
<recursiveComponent/>
}else{

<recursiveComponent optionalParam=“param”/>
}
```

Note— in-line like this doesn’t work:

```
<recursiveComponent optionalParam=“@(param == null ? null : param) ”/>
```

Comment: Typing on phone...code did not post properly

Comment: It's not clear why you think not passing a parameter would be any different to passing in a null? What type is the parameter? Why can't you fix the error when it is null?

Comment: The problem is...when I pass the parameters when they are null...it crashes

Comment: Then the problem is a bug in  your recursiveComponent. Fix it.

Comment: so helpful Henk Holterman

Comment: Why your first example doesn't work? Wich error throws?

Answer (score 0):

Try [attribute splatting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/components/?view=aspnetcore-3.1):

```
@code {
    var attributes = new Dictionary<string, object>();
    if(param != null)
        attributes["optionalParam"] = "param";
}
<recursiveComponent @attributes="attributes" />
```